# sphere.io custom fields on objects

Tags: java, sphere.io, commercetools

On [Sphere.io](http://sphere.io/), I know it is possible to attach custom data to `Product` objects, using the [custom attributes.](http://sphere.io/dev/http-api-projects-productTypes.html)

Is it possible to do something similar with the `Customer` and `Order` objects? Just untyped key-value String pairs would be fine for my scenario (For now, anyway. Later I might need to attach JSON documents).

If yes, is it also possible to filter the objects based on the custom data?

I am using the [Sphere Java SDK](https://github.com/commercetools/sphere-play-sdk).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Custom objects API](http://sphere.io/dev/http-api-projects-custom-objects.html) is a simple key-value store that can be used to extend objects such as customer or order with custom JSON documents. If you wanted to attach a birthday to a customer, you could implement it with a custom object where the *container* could be called "customer-birthdays" and the *key* would be the id of the customer. 
Every time you would load a customer object and you would require the birthday, you would have to fetch it using it's id from the key-value store.

The SPHERE.IO backend does not know anything about the associations between a customer and it's birthday. This means that when querying customers it is not possible to include the attached birthday in the query predicate.

The custom objects API is also exposed in the Java SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you were looking for has now (4th of August 2015) been added to the commercetools platform (formerly known as SPHERE.IO). You can check the [release notes](http://dev.sphere.io/release-notes.html).

There's a new "types" endpoint that lets you define globally reusable types. Then you can set the type at an order and that specific order gains the attributes defined in the type.